# Calling JS function from JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to call a script function from the JSP page, but it returns me a reference error. This must be a pretty basic concept but I have searched a lot and couldn't find the solution.

> ReferenceError: sayhello is not defined

```html
<script>
  function sayhello() {
    console.log("Hello world");
    alert(1);
  }
</script>
<button onclick="sayhello()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: The code you've shown works fine. The error you've got is either because the `sayhello()` function is not defined at the point you try to call it, or is out of scope. Without seeing the actual code which re-creates the error we cannot debug the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The code is quite big to put it here but it doesnt work whereever i put it. I even tried creating a new "<script> "mt func def" </script>" but it stil gives me the same error. Any ideas why it could be?

Comment: Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Swati911/m08e1uc4/) its working.

Comment: Thank @Swati, i know the code works outside my project but due to some reason its not working in my project. Do you have any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: where is `script` located in `head` tag ?